# Static member destruction

Tags: c++, windows, dll, static

I'm not a fan of statics but I've got some code that has:

The static destruction will fail unless something else is around. The static is declared as a member inside of a DLL class.

The executable is shutting down so runtime calls FreeLibary to release the DLLs it loaded at start up.

I know the static will be destroyed during termination of my program (no guarantees on destruction order since there was no guarantee for construction order) but when will it be be READY for destruction? After my `DLLMain` (for the loaded DLL) is exited or after the runtimes `__DllMainCRTStartup` or even after this?

I just want to know if I will get the chance to do something before destruction, if not I will need to look into removing the static to something more appropriate.

Comment: Apostrophe attack, everyone take cover!

Comment: A consideration is what is it that you want to do before destruction and the timing of that with the various other destruction and termination activities.  If what you want to do will depend on other parts of the system, those parts may or may not be in place.  So trying to time some action based on the destruction may not be the most appropriate approach.

Comment: What is it that needs to happen before destruction of this static member object?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, it was pretty dire. Randomly removed a few.

Comment: The static object contains a ComPtr. This needs the COM library around for it to be removed successfully.

Comment: OK. What is the life time of this ComPtr? When does it go out of scope in the program?

Comment: The lifetime will be that of the static object, that is the problem. It is contained within a static object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the **atexit** function will help you.  You give it a callback function that will be executed by the runtime during process detach.

DLL Explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/988ye33t.aspx

atexit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tze57ck3.aspx

Comment: This will work in the general case of clearing up statics and is good to know therefore marking as answer. In my case it won't work, because the COM Library is gone by the time atexit callback is called.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I understand you are on Windows, and with Microsoft compilers. My answer is specific to this settings (although I'm pretty sure gcc is similar).

The short answer is:
As long as your DLL is around, and it has dependency on another DLL, and you don't screw up things (e.g. You don't FreeLibrary the dependency), then the dependency DLL is still in memory in a working condition, and can be called.
The shutdown sequence on the dependent DLL will start only after you DLL has be completely shutdown.

The sequence order on a DLL compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio:

- DllMainCRTStartup is the entry point of your DLL. You can see code of this method at: **c:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\CRT\src\crtdll.c**
- DllMainCRTStartup calls CRT_INIT (same file).
- In DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH there is all sort of initialization. It then call the function **initterm**. This function (implemented elsewhere, see below) is the one that calls the constructor of all static C++ objects.
- In DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, CRT_INIT calls bunch of onexit/atexit routines which does the destruction.
- After calling CRT_INIT, DllMainCRTStartup calls the user defined DllMain.
- terminit is implemented in crt0dat.c. It has an array of pointers to functions (generated by the compiler and the linker) which are called in a loop. Each function is a constructor to a static object.

Answer (score 0):

I think another possible way around this would be to have a global class who's constructor simply calls `CoInitilize` and destructor calls `CoUninitilize`.

Then make sure this global is created before the object that contains say a `ComPtr`. Since destruction will be in reverse of construction, the destructor who calls `CoUninitilize` will happen after `.Release` has been called on the `ComPtr`.